# mysqldump append record if not found

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

I have two databases, one on the localhost (staging DB) and another on a remote server (Live DB). Initially, the staging DB was exactly as same as Live DB. I did some testing on the staging DB and I now wants to move those changes to the Live DB. But the issue is that in this time period, the Live DB has some other changes and isn't at the point where I left it for testing on the staging DB.

I want to retain the records of the Live DB but also want to add the updated or new records from the staging DB. And, I don't want to do it manually as this process is going to be done a lot of times in the future.

I thought of fetching all the tables without `DROP TABLE` command. I also used `sed` to change `CREATE TABLE` command to `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` to make sure I don't miss any table from the staging DB. Next, I added `--insert-ignore` option to the `mysqldump` but this doesn't help my situation. And, I don't want to use `REPLACE` command as it is very destructive.

Here is my `mysqldump` command:

```
`which mysqldump` --defaults-file=./local.cnf --insert-ignore --skip-add-drop-table --compress --create-options --add-locks --skip-opt ${STAGE_DB} > dump.sql
```

**What I want to achieve?**

To update the staging DB to Live DB without losing any data from the Live DB and still having the records from staging DB.

I'm a novice in `mysql`, so please help me out to figure this problem out.

Comment: you want to retain the data from prob and schema changes from staging and merged to staging DB is that you want?

Comment: @avisheks I want to retain data of Live DB and yet merge from stage DB to Live DB